# Как заставить работать ограниченное количество потоков в C#?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Возникла некоторая задача(скорее интерес распирает меня самого, ибо я только начал разбираться в потоках) написать следующую программу:
для некоторого порта проверить имеются ли подключения в адресах в отрезке от a до b, при этом ограничить количество потоков(что у меня не получилось)
где a начальный IP
b - конечный IP
Написал следующий код, хотелось бы услышать заметки, советы, а так же узнать что почитать(желательно на понятном языке) как это реализовывается. Заранее спасибо

```
async void rangeChecker(byte[] startIP, byte[] endIP)
        {

            await (Task.Run(() =>
            {
                int count = 0;
                while (startIP[0] != endIP[0] || startIP[1] != endIP[1] || startIP[2] != endIP[2] || startIP[3] != endIP[3])
                {
                    if (startIP[3] != 255) startIP[3]++;
                    else
                    {
                        if (startIP[2] != 255) startIP[2]++;
                        else
                        {
                            if (startIP[1] != 255) startIP[1]++;
                            else
                            {
                                if (startIP[0] != 255) startIP[2]++; else break;
                                startIP[1] = 0;
                            }
                            startIP[2] = 0;
                        }
                        startIP[3] = 0;
                    }
                    string current = (startIP[0] + "." + startIP[1] + "." + startIP[2] + "." + startIP[3]);
                    Console.WriteLine(startIP[0] + "." + startIP[1] + "." + startIP[2] + "." + startIP[3]);
                    Thread myThread = new Thread(
                        ()=>
                        {
                            CheckPortConection(current, this.port);
                        }
                        );
                   
                    myThread.Start();
                    count++;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Checked IPs : " + count);

            }));

        }
        public static void CheckPortConection(string currentIP, int port)
        {
            using (TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    tcpClient.Connect(currentIP, port);
                    Console.WriteLine(currentIP+":"+port + " Port open");
                    
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(currentIP + ":" + port + "Port closed");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: что значит ограничить количество потоков?

Comment: значит у нас есть N потоков, которые будут выполнять проверку подключения к IP, если поток заканчивает работу, он он освобождает память и мы вызываем новый, чтобы одновременно работало не более N потоков, чтобы не загружать систему. Проблема написанного мной кода в том что если у нас 10000 IP, то он создаст 10000 потоков для их проверки, а это может перегрузить ПК

Comment: Насколько я знаю, когда поток закончит свое выполнение он вернется в пул потоков и потом при создании нового потока он просто будет браться из пула

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сейчас для этого модно использовать `SemaphoreSlim`:

```
private static SemaphoreSlim semaphore;

async void rangeChecker(byte[] startIP, byte[] endIP)
{
    ...
    semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(5); // или сколько максимум нужно потоков
    while(...)
    {
        ...
        semaphore.Wait(); // либо await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        Thread myThread = new Thread(
        ...
    }
}

public static void CheckPortConection(string currentIP, int port)
{
    try
    {
        ...
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

Ну и вообще хорошо бы уже без потоков писать, а на `Task`-ах с `async`/`await`.

Comment: _Автору вопроса:_ Этот паттерн с семафором очень популярен и является самым простым и всего возможного, когда надо одновременно ограниченное количество задач выполнять. Рекомендую просто поискать еще примеров с `SemaphoreSlim`, если данный вдруг окажется не до конца понятным. И создание потока - штука дорогая по ресурсам, поэтому лучше использовать `Task.Run()`, он переиспользует уже созданные потоки из пула.

Comment: Спасибо большое, как закончится егэ обязательно почитаю

Answer (score 2):

Переделаем получение IP адресов

```
IEnumerable<string> getIPRange(byte[] startIP, byte[] endIP)
{
    while (startIP[0] != endIP[0] || startIP[1] != endIP[1] || startIP[2] != endIP[2] || startIP[3] != endIP[3])
    {
        if (startIP[3] != 255) startIP[3]++;
        else
        {
            if (startIP[2] != 255) startIP[2]++;
            else
            {
                if (startIP[1] != 255) startIP[1]++;
                else
                {
                    if (startIP[0] != 255) startIP[2]++; else break;
                    startIP[1] = 0;
                }
                startIP[2] = 0;
            }
            startIP[3] = 0;
        }
        string current = (startIP[0] + "." + startIP[1] + "." + startIP[2] + "." + startIP[3]);
        yield return current;
    }
}
```

Переделаем проверку тоже

```
public static async Task CheckPortConection(string currentIP, int port)
{
    using (TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(currentIP, port);
            Console.WriteLine(currentIP + ":" + port + " Port open");

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(currentIP + ":" + port + "Port closed");
        }
    }
}
```

Как это вызвать

```
int port = 1;
var tasks = getIPRange(null, null)
    .Select(x=>CheckPortConection(x, port))
    .ToList();
    
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

И никаких ограничений не надо, этот код не будет блокировать потоки.

Answer (score 1):

Переделаем получение IP адресов

```
IEnumerable<string> getIPRange(byte[] startIP, byte[] endIP)
{
    while (startIP[0] != endIP[0] || startIP[1] != endIP[1] || startIP[2] != endIP[2] || startIP[3] != endIP[3])
    {
        if (startIP[3] != 255) startIP[3]++;
        else
        {
            if (startIP[2] != 255) startIP[2]++;
            else
            {
                if (startIP[1] != 255) startIP[1]++;
                else
                {
                    if (startIP[0] != 255) startIP[2]++; else break;
                    startIP[1] = 0;
                }
                startIP[2] = 0;
            }
            startIP[3] = 0;
        }
        string current = (startIP[0] + "." + startIP[1] + "." + startIP[2] + "." + startIP[3]);
        yield return current;
    }
}
```

Вторая функция остается той же

```
public static void CheckPortConection(string currentIP, int port)
{
    using (TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            tcpClient.Connect(currentIP, port);
            Console.WriteLine(currentIP + ":" + port + " Port open");

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(currentIP + ":" + port + "Port closed");
        }
    }
}
```

Ну и как вызвать с ограничением количества потоков

```
int port = 1;
Parallel.ForEach(getIPRange(null, null), // ваши параметры
        new ParallelOptions() {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10},
        ip=>CheckPortConection(ip, port));
```

Comment: У меня точно в глазах не двоится? :)

Comment: @aepot ответы то разные, один Parallel.Foreach, другой на основе тасков

Comment: Действительно, с мобилки не разглядел. Я раньше думал, что в таких случаях несколько вариантов решения нужно в один ответ объединять.

Comment: @aepot не вижу смысла это делать, варианты совершенно разные и даже решают разные задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Такое делается через очередь сообщений MSMQ, RabbitMQ. Устанавливается количество потоков обрабатывающих очередь сообщений. Как только поток освободится берёт следующее сообщение на обработку. Ну и соответственно те кто скидывают сообщения в очередь

Comment: Мне кажется, для подобных задач, как у автора, AMQP - это перебор. Но да, штука полезная и быстрая.